# Assistance with multiple WHERE clauses to allow user to search by either, without each other stomping on the way

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have the simple code below

```
SELECT
      c.account,
      c.apar_id,
      c.amount,
      c.client,
      c.dim_2,
      c.dim_7,
      c.due_date,
      c.ext_inv_ref,
      c.period,
      c.voucher_date,
      c.voucher_no,
      c.voucher_type,
      c.sequence_no,
      c.rest_amount
      FROM acutrans c
      LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue r6
      ON r6.client = 'WEBE' AND r6.attribute_id = 'A4' AND r6.rel_attr_id = 'ZG06' AND c.apar_id = r6.att_value

      WHERE 
      c.client = 'WEBE' 
      AND c.period <='202007'
      AND (c.apar_id IS NULL OR c.apar_id ='CL25791') 
      OR (r6.rel_value IS NULL OR r6.rel_value ='*')
      AND (c.dim_7 IS NULL OR c.dim_7 >='') 
      AND (c.dim_7 IS NULL OR c.dim_7 <='BR36')
```

Users want to be able to search data, by either:
c.apar_id
r6.rel_value
c.dim_7

I seem on testing, to get a mix up of data, that doesn't match each other.
Your help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Please advise how can I upload data sample for query above, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses (in general) when you mix `AND` and `OR`.  I can only speculate on what you really want, but something like:

```
WHERE c.client = 'WEBE' AND
      c.period <= '202007' AND
      (c.apar_id IS NULL OR c.apar_id = 'CL25791')  AND
      ((r6.rel_value IS NULL OR r6.rel_value = '*') AND
       (c.dim_7 IS NULL OR c.dim_7 >= '') AND
       (c.dim_7 IS NULL OR c.dim_7 <= 'BR36')
      )
```

Comment: Many thanks. If I used a CASE in WHERE, would that work better?

Comment: @Bruno . . . The general advice is to not use `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause, because it enforces sequential processing and impedes the optimizer.  There are some cases where it is useful, but by not just stick with `AND`, `OR`, and parentheses?

Comment: ok, will try and do AND and OR. Thanks again Gordon, big help indeed. Many blessings